# how to extract a substring from a string in Python with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

`<b>Status : Active<br>Code : C1654<br><br>Shop <a class="top"<b>Shop A</b></a></b>`

And I want get `Active` , `C1654` and `Shop A`.

How to do the same thing in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use python `re` module
(you didn't explain the pattern you wanted to follow so I can just give an example that will work for the above string):

```
import re
results = []
reg = '.*?>.*?: (.+?)<br'
my_str = '<b>Status : Active<br>Code : C1654<br><br>Shop <a class="top"<b>Shop A</b></a></b>'
results+=re.findall(reg,my_str)
reg2 = '<a.*?<b>(.*?)</b>'
results += re.findall(reg2,my_str)
print result
>>>['Active', 'C1654', 'Shop A']
```

I hope I helped

Comment: It worked, thanks @Rptk99

Comment: @heroku no problem!, happy to help